# Two-way binding with $routeParams?

Tags: angularjs

When using `ng-view` and `$routeProvider`, it's possible to inject `$routeParams` to get values of the path, like `/foo/:id/:user/:item`. Is there any way to set those parameters in the path? Something like `$routeParams.id = 3`, and then have that reflected in the url.

I know this effect could be achieved through `$location.path()`, but I'm hoping to for a higher level of abstraction that doesn't require string manipulation.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I managed to solve the problem.

**Controller**:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$log', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
  function(scope, console, route, routeParams, location) {
    console.log('MainCtrl.create');
    scope.route = route;
    scope.routeParams = routeParams;
    scope.location = location;

    //1. This needs to be enabled for each controller that needs to watch routeParams
    //2. I believe some encapsulation and reuse through a service might be a better way
    //3. The reference to routeParams will not change so we need to enable deep dirty checking, hence the third parameter

    scope.$watch('routeParams', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      angular.forEach(newVal, function(v, k) {
        location.search(k, v);
      });
    }, true);
  }]);
```

**Module declaration + route definition**:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', [], [
      '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
        routeProvider.when('/main', {
          template : 'Main',
          controller : 'MainCtrl',
          reloadOnSearch : false
        });
      } ]);
```

**Template**:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="#/main">No Params</a>
  <a href="#/main?param1=Hello&param2=World!">With Params</a>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <p>
    <span>param1</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="routeParams['param1']">
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>param2</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="routeParams['param2']">
  </p>

  <pre>location.path() = {{location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>routeParams = {{routeParams}}</pre>
</body>
```

**Demo**:

- [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1kw6xoAlAwQKJrqTD2Y)

**References**:

- [routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams)

Answer (score 1):

As well, if you want two-way databinding for url parameters with $location, this simple function will help.

```
bind_var_to_urlparam = function(variable_name, scope){
  // initial loading from urlparams and then
  // set a watch function to update the urlparams on update
  scope[variable_name] = $location.search()[variable_name];
  scope.$watch(variable_name, function(newVal, oldVal){
    var search_obj = {};
    search_obj[variable_name] = newVal;
    $location.search(search_obj);
  });
}
```

I use this from a shared service, that is why scope is passed in.

Comment: I like it! Note, however, that this isn't really two-way databinding. When the function is called, the scope variable is set to the current value of the URL param, and after that, URL param is updated when scope variable changes. If two scopes bind to the same URL param, one scope changing it will not update the variable in the other scope. This is sufficient for many purposes though.

Comment: That's true, good point regarding different scopes binding to the same URL param.

Answer (score 0):

I use a service to create a two-way binding:

```
angular.module('app').service('urlBinder', ['$location', function($location) {
    this.bindOnScope = function(scope, name, urlParamName) {
        // update the url when the scope variable changes
        var unhookUrlUpdater = scope.$watch(name, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
                $location.search(urlParamName, newValue);
            }
        });

        // update the scope variable when the url changes
        var unhookScopeUpdater = scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
            var value = $location.search()[urlParamName];

            if (!angular.equals(scope[name], value)) {
                scope[name] = value;
            }
        });

        // return a function to remove the hooks. Note that since these hooks are set up on the scope passed in, if that scope gets destroyed (e.g. because the user went to a different page and the controller is no longer present), then the hooks will be removed automatically.
        return function() {
            unhookUrlUpdater();
            unhookScopeUpdater();
        };
    };

    // the same thing but using getter/setter functions for when you want to bind to something not on the scope
    this.bind = function(scope, getter, setter, urlParamName) {
        var unhookUrlUpdater = scope.$watch(getter, function(newValue) {
            $location.search(urlParamName, newValue);
        });

        var unhookScopeUpdater = scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
            var value = $location.search()[urlParamName];

            if (!angular.equals(getter(), value)) {
                setter(value);
            }
        });

        return function() {
            unhookUrlUpdater();
            unhookScopeUpdater();
        };
    };
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // if binding to something on the scope:
    urlBinder.bindToScope($scope, 'something', 'url-name');
    $scope.something = 'test';

    // or if the variable you want to bind isn't on the scope:
    var someVariable;
    urlBinder.bind(
        $scope,
        function() { return someVariable; },
        function(value) { someVariable = value; },
        'url-name');
}]);
```

You can then for example bind an input to the url:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="something" />
</div>
```

You may also need to set `reloadOnSearch : false` in your route config, as you don't want the controller scope to be destroyed and recreated whenever the *search* bit of the url changes.